# How can I have impromptu not continue until submit is done and exits

Tags: jquery, impromptu

I'm using the jQuery impromptu library and not understanding the async nature of it.  I've got some code below that I want to redirect after the prompt is run.  I don't want the next line of code to execute if my data.redirectPage statement is true.

```
               success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirectPage == "hackathonregistration") {
                        $.prompt("Your code has been accepted and you will now be redirected to the hackathon registration page",
                        {
                            submit: function() {
                                window.location.href = "/Register/hackathon";
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I read *fast* about [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/), your code looks ok.
*Except the missing `}` to close your `success` function...* ;)

**AND** no buttons on the submit you try to trigger.
*That is an important **AND.***

Try this :

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.redirectPage);
    if (data.redirectPage == "hackathonregistration") {
        $.prompt("Your code has been accepted and you will now be redirected to the hackathon registration page",
        {
            buttons: { "Yes": true, "No": false },
            submit: function(e,v,m,f) {
                // use e.preventDefault() to prevent closing when needed or return false.
                // e.preventDefault();
                console.log("Value clicked was: "+ v);
                if(v){
                    window.location.href = "/Register/hackathon";
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I *suppose* `v` is the bolean true/false.
Like said, I read *real fast* on Impromtu.

Personnaly, I use [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). Look for it as an alternative... May be easier.